# Changing the primary key name in a ASP .NET MVC model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My model class is:

```
 public class Contracts
    {
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
        public string contract { get; set; }            
    }
```

Add its controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var contracts = from c in db.Contracts
                            select c;
            return View(contracts.ToList());    
        }
```

The strongly typed view returns:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ContractId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.contract
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Originally the base table's primary key was called **ID**.  Then I changed it to **ContractId** for usage in foreign-keys.

How do I set the models primary key so that the view will recognize it?

**UPDATE1**: I am using EntityFramework 4

**UPDATE2**: The answer provided by Brian does correctly assign the key manually.  To solve my problem required renaming the table to 'Contracts' from 'contract'.  I also renamed the 'contract' field in that table to 'Name'.  Then I deleted the 'Contracts' model class and recreated it as 'Contract'.  The VIEW folder was renamed to Contract.  My guess is the naming conventions were breaking the code recognition of the primary key.

Comment: Your question doesn't relate specifically to MVC.  Which ORM tool are you using?  Linq to SQL?  EF?

Comment: @Jacob - Updated my question - I am using EF 4

Comment: Actually, this relates to MVC routing and doesn't have anything to do with his ORM other than the fact that he is using the same class for data access and the view model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your action methods on the controller something like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id){
    // retrieve contract and generate view
}
      public ActionResult Edit(int id){
    // retrive contract and generate view
}
      public ActionResult Delete(int id){
    // delete contract
}
```

Then your view should look like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {    
   <tr>        
      <td>
          @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ContractId }) |
          @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ContractId }) |
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ContractId })
      </td>
      <td>@item.ContractId</td>
      <td>@item.contract</td>
   </tr>
}
```